# Тип придаточного

Tags: синтаксис

Как охарактеризовать придаточное? Оно изъяснительное или — места?

***Чего не знаешь, туда и тянет.***

Comment: Не совсем удачно построено предложение (местоимения слишком разноплановые): чего не знаешь, **к тому** и тянет.

Comment: Вы правы, но это пословица.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему, пословица звучит по-другому: *чего не знаешь, туда и **не** тянет*. Это ведь на тему "Чужбина-родина".

Если говорить о типе придаточного, будем исходить от смысла. По вопросу от наречия **туда** трудно определить смысловую связь между главным и  придаточным, потому что конструкция разговорная, нарушено соотношение туда-куда, к тому-к чему. Если бы вместо **туда** было нормированное  **к тому**, звучало бы так: К тому тянет(или не тянет) (к чему именно? к какому тому?), чего не знаешь. Чего - союзное слово. Указательное слово в главном пропустить нельзя, нарушится связь к тому(=туда)- к чему, следовательно, это СПП с **местоимённо-определительным** придаточным.

Если бы указательное слово в главном можно было пропустить, это было бы СПП с придаточным изъяснительным.

Answer (score 2):

**Чего не знаешь, туда и тянет**. Пословица о любопытстве. http://posloviz.ru/category/o-ljubopytstve/

Или: **Тянет к тому, чего не знаешь.** А это СПП с **придаточным изъяснительным (вмещающий тип)**. К тому и туда ― обязательные местоименные соотносительные слова, придаточное разъясняет их содержание.

В лингвистике  этот тип занимает промежуточное положение между местоименными и изъяснительными придаточными, их можно назвать **приместоименными изъяснительными.**